Quick trick for the shortest distance from a point to a line?
I have been asked to find the shortest distance between $(0, -2)$ and $5x + 12y = 11$. I could find the line perpendicular to the latter, and find where $(0, -2)$ would lie on it. However, that sounds like it would take a while, and this question was found on a competition paper which permits about 10 seconds per question. How can this problem be solved in such a short amount of time?

There is a formula for distance from a point to a line, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line

Presuming you had no knowledge of a formula , this is probably shorter than that method.
Draw a triangle on the axes consisting of the point you describe, the line, and the line perpendicular to that line through the point as below:

The length of the line along the axes is trivial (as you can just set $x=0$ , to get $y=\frac{11}{12}$). We also know the angle at the bottom of the triangle is $\arctan(\frac{5}{12})$ (change in y over change in x). So the distance is $(2+11/12)\cos(\arctan(\frac{5}{12}))=\frac{35}{13}$

If the question was to find the nearest point rather than the distance, a variation on this approach is to infer that the purple line is $12x-5(y-2)=0$ since it should be perpendicular to the original line and pass through $(0,-2)$.  But since they want the distance, this trig approach is better.

The line is defined by $a\cdot x = 11$, where $a = [5, 12]$ is the normal vector.
Let $y = [0, -2]$.
Let $x$ be the projection of $y$ onto the line, so $y-x$ is parallel to $a$. We have:
$$|y-x| = \frac{|a\cdot(y-x)|}{|a|} = \frac{|a\cdot y - a\cdot x|}{|a|} = \frac{|-24 - 11|}{13} = \frac{35}{13}$$

You can use the formula for the distance between a line and a point:
\begin{align}
d(P, l)=\frac{|ax_P + by_P + c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2\;}}
\end{align}
where $P=(x_P,\;y_P)$ and $l$ is the line defined by the equation $ax+by+c=0$
